# Vaadin 21 Migration to View-Based Access Control - RolesAllowed not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, vaadin, vaadin21

*This is a follow up question to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69442124/vaadin-flow-21-upgrade-from-20-all-routes-suddenly-return-404).*

I migrated my Vaadin 20 application to 21 to use view-based access control. The Annotations `@PermitAll` and `@AnonymousAllowed` are working fine. However when I try to restrict a route to a specific user role with `@RolesAllowed` I can't get access to this site (being logged in with a user who has this role).
Is there some special code required to get Vaadin to recognize the roles of my authenticated user?

Role restricted page:

```java
@Component
@Route(value = "admin", layout = MainLayout.class, absolute = true)
@RolesAllowed("admin")
@UIScope
public class AdminView ...
```

SecurityConfig

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class, "/login");
    }
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        super.configure(auth);
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/images/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `@RolesAllowed({"ROLE_ADMIN"})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of debugging, I found the problem, the implementation of the `getAuthorities()` Function in my implementation of `UserDetails.java` was incorrect. A working dummy version with one role looks something like this:

```java
    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of( new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + "admin"));
    }
```

Important was to add `"ROLE_"` in front of the actual role name. Then I can use `@RolesAllowed("admin")` in the view class.

Answer (score 1):

The roles you pass into `@RolesAllowed` are case-sensitive and should match the roles you have in Spring Security. Most likely in your case, you want to use `@RolesAllowed({"ROLE_ADMIN"})`. You can read more in the docs here https://vaadin.com/docs/v21/flow/integrations/spring/view-based-access-control/#annotating-the-view-classes