# Vaadin 23 throws RouteNotFoundException although it exists

Tags: vaadin, url-routing, vaadin-flow

I upgraded Vaadin 14 to 23 and i'm having problems when trying to access a view. I'm using RouterLinks, but every single time I click a menu item in order to navigate to another view, it throws "Oops you hit a 404. Go to the front page".

All my views have @Route annotation as the official documentation states.

It was working perfectly in Vaadin 14 and I don't know what happened, since I followed the official upgrading instructions.

------ **UPDATE** -------

The problem seems to be related to the @Secured annotation. @RolesAllowed is also causing troubles. I tried changing it to @AnonymousAllowed and it works well. What could that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could solve it adding "ROLE_" before the user role, according to the answer found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/69477089/16373572